# Can we have a category of compactifications?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, compactness, compactification, slice-category

Is there any work on compactifications of spaces in terms of category theory? I would like to know whether there is a defined category of compactifications; I will denote it ***Comp***.

1. Could you describe *Comp* like this?

- Objects = compactifications
- Morphisms = homeomorphisms between compactifications?

2. Also, intuitively a Stone-Čech compactification is a "biggest" object and an Alexandroff compactification is a "smallest" object of *Comp*. Would they have any special properties then? I.e. would they be initial and terminal objects respectively?

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: I suppose you start with a fixed space $X$ and you consider as objects all compactifications of $X$. The morphisms could be continuous maps between these spaces, but it seems natural to also ask the following:  if $\alpha: X \to K$ and $\beta: X \to L$ are compactifications, then we should also require that a continuous map $f: K \to L$ satisfies $f\alpha = \beta$. You can check that you still get a category in this way. With the above proposal, the Stone-Cech compactification is terminal in this category by its universal property.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Did you mean that the Stone-Cech compactification is initial?

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes I was too fast. Every continuous map $f: X \to K$ extends uniquely to a map $\beta X \to K$ so initial object because the arrows start in the Stone-Cech compactification.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Why not an official answer?

Comment: @Paul Frost Because I only answered part of the question. I can answer (1) and (2) but (3) is too general to give a complete answer.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thank you. Would that also mean that Alexandroff comapctification is terminal object in such category? (I suppose you meant that Stone-Čech is initial). And could you recommend some resources where to read about compactifications in terms of category theory?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova I don't think that the Alexandroff compactification is terminal (if it would, it would satisfy some nice universal property, but I'm not aware of such a thing). A formal argument is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608761/is-the-one-point-compactification-terminal-in-the-category-of-compactifications I don't know about any reference about compactifications in the context of category theory.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Is it really true that Stone-Čech is initial? Would you prove it via the universal property? What construction would you use?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova I"d use the universal property as the definition of Stone-Cech compactification. To construct it I'd take the closure of the image of the embedding of the the given (completely regular) space $X$ in the compact product space $[0,1]^F$, where $F$ is the set of continuous maps $f:X\to[0,1]$ and the embedding of $X$ into the product has $f$-th component equal to $f$.